# Generar patrón: nombredearchivo_001.txt en Android

Tags: java, android

Crear un sistema de auto asignación de nombres para archivos con patrón mas un autoicrementador con un identificador de tres cifras `999`.

El patrón a seguir seria `nombrearchivo.txt` en caso de existir `nombrearchivo_???.txt`

Caso práctico:
Si en la carpeta ya existe un archivo con `newfile.txt` opte por `newfile_001.txt` u sucesivamente si existiese el anterior, por `newfile_002.txt`

Comment: Buenas, que has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución:

```
public static String generateFileNamePattern(String filePath, int count) {
    if (filePath == null) return null;
    String ext = (getExtension(filePath).length() > 0) ? "." + getExtension(filePath):"";

    return String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
            "%s/%s%03d%s",
            getPath(filePath),
            getBaseName(filePath),
            count,
            ext);
}
```

Su uso:

```
String fullPath = "/storage/emulated/0/My Documents/new_file.txt";
File file = new File(fullPath);
int i = 0;
while ((file.exists())) {
    ++i;
    file = new File(FileDirUtils.generateFileNamePattern(fullPath, i));

    Log.d(TAG, "generateFileNamePattern: " + file);
}
try {
    FileDirUtils.createFile(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Resultado:
Crea el archivo con el patrón:

```
D/FileDirUtils: createFile: /storage/emulated/0/My Documents/new_file001.txt
D/FileDirUtils: createFile: /storage/emulated/0/My Documents/new_file002.txt
```

Dejo el [Git: FileDirUtils.java](https://gist.github.com/webserveis/f00e652a079e8e092b069d234610f905) en mi Github

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, aquí te dejo un ejemplo (que no he probado) que básicamente es un bucle que busca por el patrón que comentaste:

> newfile.txt opte por newfile_001.txt u sucesivamente si existiese el
>   anterior, por newfile_002.txt

```
 String lastFileFoundName; //global

    String fileName = "newfile";
    String ext = ".txt";
    int count = 0;
      try {
          fileExists(fileName, ext, count);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

public void fileExists(String fileName, String ext, int count) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(count != 0 ?
            fileName + "_" + String.format("%03d", count) + ext : fileName + ext);
    if (file.exists()) {
        lastFileFoundName = file.getName();
        count++;
        fileExists(fileName, ext, count);
    } else {
        System.out.println("El archivo " + lastFileFoundName + " es el último");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, cuando pueda lo probaré, así por encima tiene buena pinta

Comment: No funciona, pero utilizare cosas, cuando este subo la solución